# TeamViewer auto end session or display logon screen

Tags: security, operating-system, remote-desktop

For security reason, is it possible to have TeamViewer end session after certain of idle time? Btw, I have tried to run screen saver after a period of idle time, but it seems not running at all on TeamViewer.

Is there anyway that I can have achieve auto end session or display logon screen after a period of idle time on TeamViewer?

Thanks.